# ExpressJS showing empty req.body object on POST request, but not with Insomnia or cURL

Tags: node.js, express, curl, post

I am tryin to include a global payment gateway (GPG checkout) to my MERN website.

After the payment process is done, the GPG server should send me a post request using cURL to a route I set in the GPG dashboard. The content of this post request is: PayAmount, PAYID, TransStatus, Signature.

This is my route:

```
router.route('/confirm-payment-detailes').post(async (req,res)=>{
    
    //const {TotalAmount,PAYID,TransStatus,Signature} = req.body;
    //console.log({TotalAmount,PAYID,TransStatus,Signature});

    // show any post request content to this route 
    console.log(req.body)
});
```

I am showing all POST fields I get on that route.

When I test using insomnia or cURL on my laptop, it shows me the data that I did send in server log, But it shows empty object when I complete the payment process (which means that the GPG checkout server knows my notification URL and sends a POST request but it shows empty anyway).

I called support team and they send me a PHP example of notification page:

```
<?php
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$my_url = explode('wp-content' , $url); 
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$my_url[0];

$PayAmount    = $_POST['TotalAmount'];
$PAYID     = $_POST['PAYID'];
$TransStatus   = $_POST['TransStatus'];
$Signature = $_POST['Signature'];

include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';

$sign = sha1( $_POST['TransStatus']. $PAYID . "XXXXXXX" );

if($Signature == $sign){
    $order  = wc_get_order( $PAYID );
    switch ( $TransStatus ) {
            
        case '05' : // refus
            $order->update_status( 'wc-failed', $reason );
        break;
        case '00' : // accord
            $order->update_status( 'wc-processing', $reason );
            WC()->cart->empty_cart();
        break;
        case '06' : //annuler
            $order->update_status( 'wc-cancelled', $reason );
        break;
        case '07' : // rembourser
            $order->update_status( 'wc-refunded', $reason );
        break;
        case '08' : // Charge back 
                        
        default :
        break;
    }
    
}
?>
```

As far as I know, it's just a simple POST request! Why is my server showing empty object? While it works fine when I test with insomnia or cURL with random fields.

This is my app.js file content:

```
//imports Here : 
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const mongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
//declare app here : 
const app = express();
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views','Views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Public'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(cors());

//Clients API Routes :
app.use(process.env.CLIENT_API_PATH,require('./Routes/clientAPIRoutes'));
//Admin Pages Routes :
app.use(process.env.ADMIN_PATH,require('./Routes/adminPageRoutes'));

module.exports = app;
```

Does anyone have any idea about this problem?

**Edit :**
I did create a php file on my server to recive the data instead of the node app , and it did work by just using $_POST["field_name"] , so am really confused about that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found out the problem.

The payment gateway server is using php cURL wich it seems to be not going well wen posting data to Node/express Js apps.

So i have no way to fix it since it's their server error .

[Made PHP curl POST to nodeJS API but can't read response data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385528/made-php-curl-post-to-nodejs-api-but-cant-read-response-data)

[PHP cURL request body is undefined in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162073/php-curl-request-body-is-undefined-in-node-js)

[Node js can not read the data from curl request via php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63463873/node-js-can-not-read-the-data-from-curl-request-via-php)

Am going to report this issue. But for now , am going with this php script since i need the job done !

```
<?php
/*
    
   
    Author : Rouissi Iheb ( rouissi2017@gmail.com ) 
    Date : 27/09/2021
    stackoverflow qustion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69286519/expressjs-showing-empty-req-body-object-on-post-request-but-not-with-insomnia-o/
    
    
    This script is used to redirect the POST payment detailes recived from GPG checkout servers to the E-commerce Node/expressJs server

    reason : 
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385528/made-php-curl-post-to-nodejs-api-but-cant-read-response-data
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162073/php-curl-request-body-is-undefined-in-node-js
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63463873/node-js-can-not-read-the-data-from-curl-request-via-php
      
      
*/
function execInBackground($cmd) {
   if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
       pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); 
   }
   else {
       exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");  
   }
}
if(isset($_POST['TotalAmount']) && isset($_POST['PAYID']) && isset($_POST['TransStatus']) && isset($_POST['Signature'])){
   
   //for test only TO REMOVE ON PRODUCTION !!
    //-----------------------------
   $content = "New Post Request from : ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']." \n";
   $myfile = fopen("log.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
   fwrite($myfile, $content);
   fclose($myfile);
    //------------------------------

   $data = "TotalAmount=".$_POST['TotalAmount']."&PAYID=".$_POST['PAYID']."&TransStatus=".$_POST['TransStatus']."&Signature=".$_POST['Signature'];
   execInBackground('curl -X POST -d "'.$data.'" http://nodeserver:nodeport/some-route');
}
?>
```

About the notification link that i need to provide to recive the data on it , i had to install php on my server , create a new subdomain with ssl and added this configurations to my nginx config :

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name gpg-gateway.mywebsite.com;
        root /home/user/php-proxy;
        index index.php;
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set your content type header while sending a request from your php script. here CURL ( curl may give you output but in wrong format), postman does that for you by default. here server needs to know what type of data you are sending in a request, so it can use appropriate methods to fetch that encoded data. i.e json, xml,x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart etc

that can be done by setting **Content-Type** header in the request

set it like this `Content-Type : application/json(for json data) or xml (for xml data) or x-www-form-urlencoded`

[$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)  uses application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.
run a check in your PHP script by including this `echo $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];` and possible output might be `multipart/form-data` on the basis of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is already getting parsed in your node server.
for parsing `multipart/form-data` install npm multer middleware package `npm install multer`.

```
//imports Here : 
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const mongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
const multer= require('multer');
//declare app here : 
const app = express();
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views','Views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Public'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(multer().array()) // parses multipart/form-data
app.use(cors());

//Clients API Routes :
app.use(process.env.CLIENT_API_PATH,require('./Routes/clientAPIRoutes'));
//Admin Pages Routes :
app.use(process.env.ADMIN_PATH,require('./Routes/adminPageRoutes'));

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: I do recive data ( json or urlencoded are both working ) when i test the api.But when the GPG checkout server send the request ,i recive nothing but empty object.

Comment: i think problem lies in `Content-type` .  try parsing it for `xml` as most banking and financial APIs send and receive data in `application/xml or text/xml` format. [https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser-xml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser-xml)  check this out.

Comment: I did create a php file on my server to recive the data instead of the node app , and it did work by just using $_POST["field_name"] , so am really confused about that !

Comment: may have found a solution, $_POST  uses by default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data` checkout the edited answer